# I'm in the UK on a working holiday visa. How can I cancel the visa if I want to leave the country?

Tags: visas, uk, netherlands, working-holiday

I am a New Zealander on a Working Holiday visa in the UK.  I want to leave the UK before my visa expires to get the visa for the Netherlands before I turn 31.

How long does it take to be considered as 'having applied' for the Netherlands visa?  Is it when you have your first appointment at the IND office, or only when you have all documents/numbers (because you might not have a BSN, etc, straight away)?

Do I have to cancel my UK visa? Will getting the visa from the Netherlands do that automatically since you can't have two at one time or do I do something at the airport in the UK, or is there another process?

Comment: You can't have two UK visas at the same time.  Netherlands is a different place.  You can let your UK WH run concurrently with your Netherlands visa until it expires. People do that all the time. It's not a problem.  If you want to play it strictly by the book, you can write to UKVI in Croydon and tell them that you are leaving the UK (or in formal terminology a "Notice of Variation"), but there is no *legal* requirement to do that.

Comment: What is the significance of "turning 31"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Working holiday visas typically have age-dependent eligibility conditions. I don't know how it's interpreted in this case however.

Comment: The UK visa is not a concern, you can just go to the Netherlands and forget about it but are you sure the date of application is what matters?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  Ok, I won't worry about the UK visa. That's great because if something happens that I don't get the Netherlands visa, I can come back to the UK.

Comment: Age is important.  The WHV for the Netherlands (for NZers) is for people aged between 18 and 31.  You have to be settled in the Netherlands while still 30.  I'm just wondering at which point in the process is considered applied and ok to turn 31.

Comment: @Kiwikatie What I meant to ask is whether you are positive that you can stay for a full year if you entered/applied/settled just before you turn 31? I thought you could only stay under a WHV until your 31st birthday and the documents I read are not particularly clear on that.

Comment: Nothing is ever very clear!  I know it's OK for the UK and someone told me it was possible.  Most things I can find say this: you must enter the Netherlands in time to register at the local town hall before your 31st birthday.